# take user to certain point on page where div fades in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help, I am fading in several `div`'s on a page and each time the user closes one `div` another will fade in, what I want to try and achieve is a way to take the user up/down the page to the focal point of where the `div` is?

Is this possible and if so how could i achieve it, thanks

```
<script>
        $(".dashboard_intro_arrow3").hide();
        $(".dashboard_intro3").hide();
         $(".dashboard_intro_text3").hide();
        $(".exit_intro3").hide();
        $(".dashboard_intro_fav").hide();

        $('.exit_intro2').click(function () {
            if ($('.dashboard_intro2').is(":visible")) {
                 $(".dashboard_intro2").fadeOut(500);
                 $(".dashboard_intro_arrow2").fadeOut(500);
                 $(".exit_intro2").fadeOut(500);
                 $(".dashboard_intro_text2").fadeOut(500);
                 $('.dashboard_intro_arrow3').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
                  $('.dashboard_intro3').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
                  $('.dashboard_intro_text3').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
                  $('.exit_intro3').delay(500).fadeIn(500);


            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can use anchors on your page to scroll. When you navigate to an anchor, the page scrolls so that the anchor element is at the very top of the window.

First, make an anchor.

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

Next, make a link to that anchor.

```
<a href="#anchor">Click me!</a>
```

Or in your case, use JS to navigate.

```
location.hash = "#anchor"
```

For example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
<a name="scrollToDiv"></a>
...
</div>

<script>
location.hash = "#scrollToDiv";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```